# Rectangle does not re-render properly after transformation in react-konva

Tags: javascript, reactjs, konvajs, react-konva, konvajs-reactjs

I have been using this (https://github.com/oasis10702/konva-simple-example) code in a project of mine and everything works fine. However, updating react and react-konva to the latest version causes some to me unintended behavior. When resizing a rectangle with the transformer, it is scaling the border stroke, see image. scaleX and scaleY doesn't either seem to reset which make it perform the scaling every time i move the rectangle.

[image: Rectangle]

I'm new to both React and Konva and wonder if there is some logic that have changed during the new versions that I should consider to mitigate this.

Try to resize the rectangle in the below sandbox.
https://codesandbox.io/embed/vyv106x295
If I update the dependencies to the latest, the behaviour becomes changed.

I've tried solving it with https://github.com/konvajs/konva/issues/401 but it doesn't seem to help in this version.

Comment: How the previous version was working for you? And what is your main issue? Just stroke rendering?

Comment: The version on the github example provided in the description works perfectly fine. (That is "react, react-dom": 16.4.2, "konva": "2.2.1", "react-konva": "1.7.12")

When I have the newer versions, i seem to have problem with the scaling of the rectangles, scaleX and scaleY doesn't seem to go back to 1. I think the best way to reproduce what I'm trying to explain is to try out the github example and update everything to the latest versions.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/embed/vyv106x295

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main change was the `strict` mode. You can just enable it back for all shapes, or just one rectangle:

```
<Rect {...someProps} scaleX={1} scaleY={1}  _useStrictMode />
```

For more info see: https://github.com/konvajs/react-konva#strict-mode